# Create Unique number based on input numbers

Tags: java

I have three numbers of type Long. Say, 1001, 2005, 8001.
I need a method to generate a new number of type Long based on these three numbers. Any logic can be applied. Output should be always same whenever we use the same combination of numbers otherwise not.
I need to solve this using Java.

Comment: Can’t figured out any logic. Is this really possible?

Comment: multiply is not possible, 1*3*4 same output as 1*2*6. The output needs to be unique such a way that it should provide unique number as always as output for 3 combination of number

Comment: This seems very vague. Why do you want to do this and what should the logic be?

Comment: ok, so multiplying will not work. you say that same combination of numbers. Must the result be the same given different order? 1,3,6 must give same result as 6,1,3 or 1, 6, 3?

Comment: 1,3,6 and 6,1,3 needs to provide different output.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X concatenation is also not a option here. What if i use maximum values of Long?

Comment: @ndc85430 The requirement is like creating a random number based on three numbers provided as input. But whenever we use the same number in same order, it should return the same unique number.

Comment: Shift and Xor? But you can't get a ***unique*** long for *every* three longs. There are 2^192 possible values of three longs, and only 2^64 possible values of one.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X not required.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
long combine(long a, long b, long c) {
    return Long.rotateLeft(a, 32) ^ Long.rotateLeft(b, 16) ^ c;
}
```

I used rotate rather than shift because you said "Concatenation is also not a option here. What if I use maximum values of Long?" Shift would shift some bits right out, but rotate will only move them around. The output will depend on all the bits of all three longs, but because they are rotated by different amounts, `combine(a, b, c)` will produce a different result than `combine(c, a, b)` (unless `a == b` and `b == c`, of course).

Comment: can I ask why the decision to shift by 32 and 16 was made? would it be a problem if any other values were used to rotateLeft?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X No particular reason, they just seemed like nice numbers. You could certainly use others. 21 and 42 would be nicely equidistant divisions of 64, or maybe 23 and 41 if you prefer prime numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) may be what you need.

Hash functions map an input set to an output set, usually with the goal of it not being "easy" to know what the output will be from the input and such that small changes to the input yield different outputs. In your case the input is a tuple of three longs, and the output is a long.

It is deterministic, which fulfills your requirement for identical input yielding identical output.

From Wikipedia:

> A hash procedure must be deterministic—meaning that for a given input value it must always generate the same hash value. In other words, it must be a function of the data to be hashed, in the mathematical sense of the term.

It is impossible to guarantee that the two different inputs will have the same outputs because of the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), but a good hash function will be [*collision-resistant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance), meaning it is hard to find two inputs with the same output.

There are plenty of hash functions out there. For some examples:

- [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)
- [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3)
- [BLAKE3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function)#:%7E:text=wolfSSL-,BLAKE3,-%5Bedit%5D)

For a more extensive list see this Wikipedia article:

[List of Hash Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions)

The exact way to approach this is up to you, one implementation off the top of my head is to convert the longs to strings, concatenate them, and hash that concatted string, then return that hash as a long.